# Can I use a tank water heater as a tank?

Tags: plumbing, hot-water

It seems to me that insulated water storage tanks are much more expensive than tank water heaters.

Are there reasons I shouldn't just use a tank water heater (element turned off) as a storage tank?

Edit: The tank is intended for storage of solar-heated water, which tempers *before* a normal water heater. I could buy a Rheem Marathon plus extra tank blankets for the price of comparable insulated storage tank. I can't help but think that's it's just a marketing difference.

Comment: Insulated tanks may be better insulated than water heaters. They may also be higher quality metal; my indirectly heated tank is stainless steel. Note that without heat input, insulation is not enough to retain heat indefinitely; even a vacuum bottle doesn't achieve that...so if you are adding a tank, whatever is heating the water has to keep up with that additional loss of heat. What are you actually trying to do by adding a tank? (This looks like it might be an X/Y question.)

Comment: It will work but be conscientious that there will be heat losses probably much greater then a heated tank, depending on models.

Comment: @Gil always found solar tanks to be better quality than the generic heated tanks. Materials, design, insulation and fittings…